# I am unable to click on a Web Element using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate an application using selenium Webdriver. I frequently come across scenarios where click action does not work on the WebElements.

For instance , in the html block that looked something like :

```
<div id=staticid>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="tr1" class="class1" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="1" data-boundview="gridview-1211" role="row">
        <td id="td1" class="class2 " role="gridcell">
          <div class="class3 " style="text-align:left;" unselectable="on">Content 1</div>
        <td id="td2" class="class6" role="gridcell">
          <div class="class5" style="text-align:center;" unselectable="on">
            <img class="class4" src="chekboximage">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="td3" class="class8" role="gridcell">
          <div class="class5" style="text-align:center;" unselectable="on">
            <img class="class4" src="checkboximage">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The ids are dynamically generated and the classes are like "grid-inner.." so on. (I ve replaced them to make it smaller)
The last two  elements appear as checkboxes.
On clicking the  block, the class of the td block changes and the the checkbox appears to be clicked.

I tried to click on the checkboxes using driver.findElement(By.xpath()),csspath and everything. The click action seems to be carried out successfully but the desired result,that is ,the checkbox being checked does not happen.

I verified my xpath and csspaths using Selenium IDE. The Element gets located correctly using the "Find" option. Click action also gets performed ,but the checkboxes remain unchecked.

I ve been trying to get this done for almost a week now.
Can anyone please help me out?

The code did seem to change the image on click (I compared the image source before and after a click) . But there were no visible "onclick()" calls (I am not sure if there are other ways of invoking java script fuctions on click.Please do let me know if there are ). Anyway , I tried clicking on the  block. it works with Se-IDE and Se-IEDriver but not in FireFoxDriver.

Comment: You need to show the code that you are having problems with. Note the sample HTML you provided does not have any checkboxes. The images are what likely looks to you like a checkbox, and there is likely some javascript event in the background that switches the images back and forth.

Comment: Presumably there's a JavaScript onClick handler that changes the class of the `td`? Can you check which element this is regestered on? Which element are you finding and clicking with Selenium (`td`, `div` or `img`)? Also, is it possible that your Selenium code is running before dynamic elements have finished being generated, or before event handlers have been registered?

Comment: Have you tried the MoveToElement method?

Comment: Yes Mike , I have. It behaves the same way

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath()).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);` this also does the same as click but with keyboard stroke. Hope it works.